# Rename [black-mirrors] to [black-mirror]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/93878/19561) about [*Black Mirror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror_(TV_series)) was mistakenly tagged [black-mirrors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mirrors), while the proper tag name should be [black-mirror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mirror) (which doesn't exist yet).

**Can we have this fixed?** The tags are too similar to be fixed by a mere mortal user.

Comment: I pinged Rand about this.

Comment: Though I suspect you could make this work by (a) deleting the tag from the post, (b) waiting for the system to delete it, then (c) adding the [tag:black-mirror] tag.

Comment: In general, a moderator flag on the question would have been sufficient for this. There's really no need for a meta post when the situation is 100% non-controversial, requires practically no feedback other than the tag rename and mortal users can't do anything about it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Done:**  [black-mirror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-mirror).